# Why do I only get NAs when using left_join?

Tags: r, dplyr

I have two sets of data (.sav) from a closed off questionnaire; list of respondent IDs (2800 rows) and a list of everyone's IDs (including the respondents, 8500 rows) with added information. I want to left_join both datasets, so that I have one set (2800 rows) with the respondent IDs and their information.

Basic example below:

```
quest <- data.frame(
          a = c(1:10),
          b = c("abc", "def", "ghi", "jkl", "mno", "pqr", "stu", "vwx", "yzA", "BCD"),
          c = c(23,65,87,32,45,67,87,34,110,12))
resp <- data.frame(
          a = c(1,3,8,6,2,5))

left_join(resp, quest, by = "a")

  a   b  c
1 1 abc 23
2 3 ghi 87
3 8 vwx 34
4 6 pqr 67
5 2 def 65
6 5 mno 45
```

For some reason all the added columns only have NAs and I can't figure out why:

```
> head(panelleden,2)
# A tibble: 2 × 8
  corop coropNaam          geslacht  opleiding  leeftijd_jaren respondent lijst_id    panel_resp_id_b                 
  <chr> <chr>              <dbl+lbl> <dbl+lbl>           <dbl>      <dbl> <chr>       <chr>                           
1 CR05  Zuidwest-Friesland 2 [Vrouw] 2 [Midden]             54      10609 lijstintake ba28a5c372ca9bbb20d3613e65e0bc47
2 CR04  Noord-Friesland    1 [Man]   1 [Laag]               45      31409 lijstintake 0eff6e236090beeece4ecb5de0cc773c
> head(resp,2)
# A tibble: 2 × 1
  panel_resp_id_b                 
  <chr>                           
1 de25f0b0942ebc63172e9b2fcc265de3
2 8ee2915d22a22e6130bed90cdb3d3379
> left_join(resp, panelleden, by = "panel_resp_id_b")
# A tibble: 2,802 × 8
   panel_resp_id_b                  corop coropNaam geslacht  opleiding leeftijd_jaren respondent lijst_id
   <chr>                            <chr> <chr>     <dbl+lbl> <dbl+lbl>          <dbl>      <dbl> <chr>   
 1 de25f0b0942ebc63172e9b2fcc265de3 NA    NA        NA        NA                    NA         NA NA      
 2 8ee2915d22a22e6130bed90cdb3d3379 NA    NA        NA        NA                    NA         NA NA
```

I saw more than one question about this problem and have tried every last one of them. I used `trimws` for any whitespace in `a`, added a specific `join_by` and looked for NA values in the dataset (which were none).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your code work without any problems on my machine. Restart R.

Comment: The example does work on my laptop, but my own datasets don't. It's the exact same code tho.

Comment: then we can only help if you are able to provide some lines of your data, for example `dput(head(yourdata))`.  Otherwise it is wild guessing!

Comment: I added two rows of both datasets and the join. All the rows are NAs btw.

Comment: Those two rows have no overlaps in the join keys, "of course" you will get `NA`s for them.

Comment: Those two rows would have a very small chance of matching if the datasets in the thousands and not ordered by ID?

Comment: @DarrenTsai all the `resp` are in `quest` btw

Comment: `all(resp$panel_resp_id_b %in% panelleden$panel_resp_id_b)` returns `TRUE` or `FALSE`?

Comment: It first returned `TRUE`, but when I runned it again just to be sure, it returned `FALSE`? I think there's a problem with my data. This shouldn't be the case, at all.

Comment: FYI, this has nothing to do with the RStudio IDE, please don't spam tags. I'm removing [tag:rstudio] for now until you can demonstrate how this performance can/should behave differently in RStudio and outside of it (in R without the IDE).

Comment: Just to sum up: your "Basic example" above works just fine. You then show a 2-row example from your real data that also works just fine. So you haven't been able to show us anything that's not working as expected. I would suggest that you check your own assumptions about your data. For example, see how many values they have in common: `intersect(panelleden$panel_resp_id_b, resp$panel_resp_id_b)` - do you see as many common values as you expect? Try an inner join, where only matched rows are kept, `inner_join(resp, panelleden, by = "panel_resp_id_b")`.

Comment: My boss gave me the wrong data! I didnt check thoroughly enough, so my bad. Thanks for all your help!